# I have a partial observer error trying to export a class

Tags: typescript

So my code is based in two models and what I'm trying to do is export their class but I'm having this error, but first the code. I'm following a tutorial about a task manager from devstackr and I can't find where the error is and the video is already old. I already tried using tsconfig.json and change the strictPropertyInitialization to false but didn't work.

list.model.ts

```
  _id: string;
  title: string;
}
```

task.model.ts

```
export class Task {
  _id: string;
  title: string;
  _listId: string;
}
```

new-list.component.ts this where the error starts

```
import { TaskService } from 'src/app/task.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { List } from "src/app/models/list.model";
import {Task} from "src/app/models/task.model";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-list',
  templateUrl: './new-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-list.component.scss']
})
export class NewListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private taskService: TaskService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  createList(title: string){
    this.taskService.createList(title).subscribe((list: List) =>{
      console.log(list);
      //Redirecionar para /lists/reponse_id
      this.router.navigate(['/lists', list._id]);
    });
  }

}
```

new-task.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TaskService } from 'src/app/task.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Task } from 'src/app/models/task.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-task',
  templateUrl: './new-task.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-task.component.scss']
})
export class NewTaskComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private taskService: TaskService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

  listId: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.listId = params['listId'];
        console.log(this.listId);
      });
  }

  createTask(title: string){
    this.taskService.createTask(title, this.listId).subscribe((newTask: Task)=>{
      this.router.navigate(['../'], {relativeTo: this.route});
    });
  }

}
```

task.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { WebRequestService } from './web-request.service';
import { Task } from './models/task.model';
import { List } from './models/list.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TaskService {

  constructor(private webReqService: WebRequestService) { }


  getLists() {
    return this.webReqService.get('lists');
  }

  createList(title: string) {
    return this.webReqService.post('lists', { title });
  }

  updateList(id: string, title: string) {
    return this.webReqService.patch(`lists/${id}`, { title });
  }

  updateTask(listId: string, taskId: string, title: string) {
    return this.webReqService.patch(`lists/${listId}/tasks/${taskId}`, { title });
  }

  deleteTask(listId: string, taskId: string) {
    return this.webReqService.delete(`lists/${listId}/tasks/${taskId}`);
  }

  deleteList(id: string) {
    return this.webReqService.delete(`lists/${id}`);
  }

  getTasks(listId: string) {
    return this.webReqService.get(`lists/${listId}/tasks`);
  }

  createTask(title: string, listId: string) {
    return this.webReqService.post(`lists/${listId}/tasks`, { title });
  }
```

webrequestservice.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{ HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebRequestService {

  readonly ROOT_URL;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';
  }

  get(uri: string){
    return this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`);
  }

  post(uri: string, payload: Object){
    return this.http.post(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`, payload);
  }

  patch(uri: string, payload: Object){
    return this.http.patch(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`, payload);
  }

  delete(uri: string){
    return this.http.delete(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`);
  }
}
```

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(observer?: Partial> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Type '(lists: List[]) => void' has no properties in common with type 'Partial>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(next: (value: Object) => void): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(lists: List[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'lists' and 'value' are incompatible.
        The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
          Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'List[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | null | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(lists: List[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'lists' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'List[]'.
          The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
```

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(observer?: Partial> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Type '(tasks: Task[]) => void' has no properties in common with type 'Partial>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(next: (value: Object) => void): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(tasks: Task[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'tasks' and 'value' are incompatible.
        The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
          Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Task[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | null | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(tasks: Task[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'tasks' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Task[]'.
          The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
```

The new error that shows up

```
Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Task': _id, title, _listId, completed

Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'List': _id, title
```

Comment: Would you share your error message? Hard to help without that information.

Comment: Unrelated: You are subscribing to observables and never releasing the subscription, that has the potential to cause memory leaks.

Comment: I edited the post and there is a image of the error! My bad I don't know how stack works..

Comment: We don't like images, the actual text is much more useful, for example, it can be copy pasted

Comment: Okay I added the error. Hoping u can help me since this is a school project..

Comment: Your problem is that you are expecting the wrong parameter in the subscription from `this.taskService.createList(title)`. It says: "`(tasks: Task[]) => void'` has no properties in common with type `'Partial>`". So you need to show the signature of `taskService.createList`

Comment: sorry i couldn’t understand could you explain it better? I’m new to this type of language

Comment: The error is the fact that you are passing the wrong type of callback. **You must include the code For `TaskService#createList`** so we know what it returns and what the correct callback should be.

Comment: Okay I'll update it here so u can see it

Comment: Since you are not specifying return types in your functions , we need to know what `WebRequestService#post` returns. However, it's not going to return a `List` object unless you specifically cast it.

Comment: If you explicitly set the return type of `createList` to be an `Observable<List>`, the error message will be a little simpler.

Comment: so I have to return createList to an Observable?

Comment: I can't understand can u be explicit? this is like my first time using rxjs and angular so..I can't comprehend that well..

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: As mentioned before, change your `createList` to return an `Observable<List>` and your new error message will be simpler, post it here. `createList(title: string): Observable<List> {`

Comment: The new error shows this... I tried putting Observable<List> on the return but my data doesn't show up on the application

Comment: Help... please?

Comment: You didn't explain what your new error was. Please understand that there's a reason not many people are helping you here. You are not being clear and have not done enough debugging. You need to make sure your question is understandable without having to go through the comments. Your question should be updated with your new attempt and the error message. It's messy now for me to understand what your new error is and your post doesn't explain where the error message is from.

Comment: It looks like you may be importing `Observable` from two different places. See `Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.` Look for imports of Observable from different places.

Comment: Im sorry I'm just having a hard time making this project since it is a old tutorial and errors don't stop popping up but anyways... The error that I'm trying to fix is that my tasks is not showing or adding in the list and I tried the do the Observable that u said and give me that error.. I tried put ``return <Observable><List>` it did work but didn't show me no data... All I need is this part to be fixed and my project is done and I don't know what to do, I'm sorry.